# @SuppressWarnings annotation not recognized by compiler/text editor

Tags: java, annotations

This seems incredibly basic, but as much as I search I can't find the solution.

I want to suppress a warning in java, by adding the @SuppressWarnings annotation, but the compiler doesn't accept it, nor does the text editor give it a special color. It's like annotations don't exist.

The text editor is Notepad++, and I simply compile from the command line with the newest JDK.

```
class Table<T> implements AbstractTable<T>{

    T[] elements;

    @SuppressWarnings()
    Table(int length){
        elementer = (T[]) new Object[lengde]; //this is why I want to suppress
    }
}
```

I must be missing out on something essential, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your code ? do you have the correct imports ? What is the exact error you are encountering ? What version of java are you using ?

Comment: Thanks, added some code now.The error message depends on where I put the annotation. If I put it above the class, like in the example, it expects it to be a class declaration, if I put it above the method, it expects a method.

Comment: Post the code **with** the annotation. And the exact and complete error message you get from the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annotation is not recognized by your editor because your editor doesn't have that functionality. Notepad++ has very basic syntax highlighting based on keywords and that's pretty much it. It has no compiler to know what `@SuppressWarnings` is supposed to be - or any annotation for that matter.

As to why the compiler rejects your annotation: You haven't defined the mandatory attribute `value`. You have to tell the compiler **which** warnings to ignore, like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

if you don't want to hear about unchecked conversions.

My suggestion would be to get a proper IDE like Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA or NetBeans. Coding in Notepad++ is sufficient for a basic HelloWorld, but that's about it.